# I am getting this runtime error in java: java.util.NoSuchElementException, and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am creating a tic tac toe game in java for a homework assignment. I have a parent class called TicTacToe and a derived class called humanVsHuman.

The following method is written in the derived class. It prompts the user to enter the position that they want to enter their game piece (X or O) and then calls two methods from the parent class: One that stores the X or O in a multidemensional array called setGb() and one that displays the board with the new piece called displayBoard().

Here is the method:

```
private void playGame() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int row, col;
    System.out.println("When playing, enter the row and column position for your X or O piece separated by a space.");
    do{
        System.out.print(player1 + ", Enter X position: ");
        row = keyboard.nextInt();
        col = keyboard.nextInt();
        setGb(row, col, 'X');
        displayBoard();

        System.out.print(player2 + ", Enter O position: ");
        row = keyboard.nextInt();
        col = keyboard.nextInt();
        setGb (row, col, 'O');
        displayBoard();
        keyboard.close();
    } while (!gameOver());
}
```

I am getting the following runtime error:

```
When playing, enter the row and column position for your X or O piece separated by a space.
Deena, Enter X position: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Assignment7C.HumanVsHuman.playGame(HumanVsHuman.java:38)
    at Assignment7C.HumanVsHuman.repeatGame(HumanVsHuman.java:28)
    at Assignment7C.HumanVsHuman.game(HumanVsHuman.java:14)
    at Assignment7C.TicTacToeTest.main(TicTacToeTest.java:10)
```

I'm getting the error as soon as the prompt to enter the position is displayed and before I am able to input the position.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Deena,` where this word is coming from?

Comment: My bet: You also have a `new Scanner (System.in)` somewhere else and closed that. Closing a `Scanner` closes the underlying stream.

Comment: @VishalK:  That's defined by `player1` in the code.

Comment: Show your complete code..for better understanding of the problem..

Comment: keyboard.close in your loop needs to be out of your loop

Comment: You are getting this error after first iteration or in first iteration?

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move `keyboard.close()` out of the loop.  You don't want to close the `Scanner` until the game is over.  This will not resolve the exception in your problem, but you need to do it anyway to avoid the very next problem you will face.

Comment: Whoa! Was it something I said?

Comment: It's valid but that wouldn't be the cause of *that* particular exception...and no, I didn't downvote. :)

Comment: I tried removing the keyboard.close() and I am still getting the same error

Comment: True, I couldn't reproduce that exception.  I figured that making this change would at least be a start.  I'll edit it to make that clear.

Comment: I wasn't getting that exact error either. When I ran your code I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed` the api says `NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted` does your editor allow for console input?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the following code from your while loop and see if it works.

```
    keyboard.close();
```

Or you can add it outside the loop.